# How would one implement a data structure with test-driven development in mind?

Tags: tdd

In higher-level languages such as Java or Python, we don't usually need to implement our own data structures since the languages provide their own libraries for them.

So, for example, how would we start writing a data structure for a set with test-driven development in mind?

How would you create the tests first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common misconception about TDD is that TDD drives the entire design of a software project, that a complete software architecture naturally emerges from writing tests and getting them to pass.

That's not how TDD works.  *You still have to design your software.*

So, to begin writing a data structure for a Set using TDD, you would first determine what sort of data will be stored, how that data might be represented in memory conceptually, and then figure out what sort of behaviors you will need to store, retrieve and manipulate that data.

That should be more than enough information to begin writing tests for methods and code that implement your Set data structure.

Comment: https://violoncello2011.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/implement-a-linked-list-with-tdd/